# Button inside ScrollPane with selected item image

Tags: java, libgdx

So, I have a paged scrollpane with images using the Button actor.

```
Button img = new Button(skin);
Image foreground = new Image("foregroundImg");
Image selector = new Image("selectorImg");

img.stack(selector, foreground);
ButtonStyle style = img.getStyle();
style.over = style.up = style.down = null;
```

I'm using two Image actors because I want to animate the selector background.

Since it's a grid of elements, how can I highlight the clicked element using the selector Image that I put into the Stack?

Also, I add it to all the images but only the last image shows the selector. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't show the selector image (as background) for a clicked element inside the scrollpane

Comment: Edited to add more context.

Comment: I should have been more clear that's true, thanks for your time. I hope the last edit is clear enough to understand for anyone that would like to help.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Where lies the problem do you have a listener? Where you change the Image of Button?